# Is it possible to have an async process executed in a BackgroundWorker (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create an application to crawl a website.  I can get the necessary pages, but using the obsolete WebResponse/WebRequest functionality.  I have tried to create a function using HttpClient, but when it executes (which it does once), I get an error on the BackgroundWorker when it tries to post its response back (Worker.ReportProgress):

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'This operation has already had OperationCompleted called on it and further calls are illegal.'

This error does not occur when using the obsolete functions to get the page.  Here is the code:

```
Private Async Sub bgWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgWorker.DoWork
        Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)

        Dim inStream As StreamReader
        Dim webResponse As WebResponse
        Dim webRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(txt_Address.Text.Trim)
        Dim sSource As String

        Dim iPage As Integer


        Dim iStart As Integer
        Dim iEnd As Integer
        Dim iMaxStart As Integer

        Dim sArchive As String
        Dim sLink As String

        '~~ The following code works (but is obsolete), 
        '   but is commented out for test purposes
        'webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse
        'inStream = New StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream())

        'sSource = inStream.ReadToEnd.Trim
        'inStream.Close()

        'webResponse.Close()

        '~~ If I comment out the 'Using' block, and uncomment the above, everything works as
        '   expected.
        Using response As HttpResponseMessage = Await Client.GetAsync(sAddressBar)
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

            sSource = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        End Using

        iStart = sSource.IndexOf("imgpagebar") + 20
        iEnd = sSource.IndexOf("</h2>", iStart)
        iMaxPage = Val(sSource.Substring(iStart, iEnd - iStart))

        For iPage = 1 To iMaxPage


            If iPage <> 1 Then
                iStart = sSource.IndexOf("</h2>", sSource.IndexOf("imgpagebar")) + 15
                iEnd = sSource.IndexOf(">", iStart) - 1

                sLink = String.Concat(txt_Address.Text.AsSpan(0, txt_Address.Text.IndexOf("/", 9)), sSource.AsSpan(iStart, iEnd - iStart))

                webRequest = WebRequest.Create(sLink)
                webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse
                inStream = New StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream())

                sSource = inStream.ReadToEnd.Trim
                inStream.Close()

                webResponse.Close()
            End If

            iStart = 0
            iMaxStart = sSource.IndexOf("value") - 53

            Do
                iStart = sSource.IndexOf("picbox", iStart) + 6

                If iStart <> -1 And iStart < iMaxStart Then
                    iStart = sSource.IndexOf("href=", iStart) + 6
                    iEnd = sSource.IndexOf(">", iStart) - 1
                    sLink = sSource.Substring(iStart, iEnd - iStart)

                    iStart = sSource.IndexOf("<h9>", iStart) + 4
                    iEnd = sSource.IndexOf("</h9>", iStart)
                    sArchive = sSource.Substring(iStart, iEnd - iStart)

                    worker.ReportProgress(iPage, {sArchive, sLink, 0, "Ready"})
                Else
                    iStart = -1
                End If
            Loop While iStart > 0
        Next iPage
    End Sub

Private Sub bgWorker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgWorker.ProgressChanged


        lbl_Status.Text = "Retrieving page " & e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + " of " & iMaxPage & " (" & grid_Archives.RowCount.ToString & " folders found)"

        grid_Archives.Rows.Add({e.UserState(0), e.UserState(1), e.UserState(2), e.UserState(3)})
    End Sub
```

Now, I tried to move the the "get" to a separate function, but it won't work either.  As in:

```
 Private Shared Async Function GetWebSite(sURL As String) As Task
        Dim sWebSource As String = ""


        Using response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync(sURL)
            sWebSource = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        End Using
    End Function
```

Any ideas if it is possible to do what I am doing?  I mean, the obsolete method works, but I don't what to have obsolete code.  I think it's because the BackgroundWorker is an async process trying to execute another async process, but I could be wrong.

I have searched all over (and Microsoft is no help) about this topic, it's like a void.  Has anyone ever done anything like this?

Comment: You are not wrong.  After the Await, the rest of the code runs on an arbitrary threadpool thread.  Forced to because the thread that runs the BGW code has no synchronization provider.  The BGW has nothing else to do so completes.  Then comes the ReportProgress call.  Either don't use BGW at all or use non-async calls.

Comment: Simple answer is don't mix Async patterns with Background workers, or if you do, you need to do it carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after 6 hours and some sleep, I have found the solution.

This is the code I have to get the webpage:

```
 Dim webRequest As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, sArchive)
 webResponse = Client.Send(webRequest)
 Dim inStream = New StreamReader(webResponse.Content.ReadAsStream)
 sSource = inStream.ReadToEnd.Trim
   
 inStream.Close()
 webRequest.Dispose()
```

It replaces the commented-out code and the using ... end using block.  The reason for the Close and Dispose is because I reuse those variables later to get subsequent pages after the master page:

```
If iPage <> 1 Then
    iStart = sSource.IndexOf("</h2>", sSource.IndexOf("imgpagebar")) + 15
    iEnd = sSource.IndexOf(">", iStart) - 1

    sLink = String.Concat(txt_Address.Text.AsSpan(0, txt_Address.Text.IndexOf("/", 9)), sSource.AsSpan(iStart, iEnd - iStart))

    webRequest = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, sLink)
    webResponse = Client.Send(webRequest)
    
    inStream = New StreamReader(webResponse.Content.ReadAsStream)
    sSource = inStream.ReadToEnd.Trim

    inStream.Close()
    webRequest.Dispose()
End If
```

Now, for multi-threads, I would like to note that while you can't have an array of controls like in the old days, I did create 4 background workers and instead of having the put the worker code in each of them, I was able to put a separate sub and have the worker call the sub (with the source and e parameters) and it works good and quick.  And only one place for the actual worker code.