# Why isn't my login being carried forward in subsequent server requests (httpClient, vb.net)?

Tags: vb.net, httpclient

I am trying to create a vb.net application that will log on to a website and maintain that connection through various requests.  Here is the code that I am using to log on to:

```
Try
    webReq = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://<<URL>>/login.html")
    sPostVar = "{""username"": ""myUserName"", ""password"":""myPassword"", ""submitme"":""1""}"
    Dim buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sPostVar)
    Dim bytes = New ByteArrayContent(buffer)
    bytes.Headers.ContentType = New Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")

    Dim req1 = Client.PostAsync("https://<<URL>>/login.html", bytes).Result

    MsgBox(req1.ToString())
Catch
    MsgBox("Unable to open URL link!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "App Error!")

    Exit Sub
End Try
```

Now, when this code executes, I get the following in the message box:

```
{StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Wed, 02 Aug 2023 05:03:17 GMT
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: keep-alive
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.34
  Set-Cookie: filehosting=sd81k9t4pibbhf284ntrbl0htk; expires=Fri, 10-Nov-2023 05:03:17 GMT; Max-Age=8640000; path=/
  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-Cache: Fron up.zzup.com
  CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
  Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=S7E9dV3mcsOD1xXM%2Bz5MgfKisq0UDlXNUJu5ywDqxg1%2F9JYRm26x56bybAGKKTepdvRpiEWmlOg2oiuMcg7RJWddtQ8ZxXDuynbdMRCu7ClPkUlbvuIZptahmd8dEA%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
  NEL: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
  Server: cloudflare
  CF-RAY: 7f03c6054cd48dde-MIA
  Alt-Svc: h3=":443"
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
  Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
}}
    Content: {System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent}
    Headers: {Date: Wed, 02 Aug 2023 05:03:17 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.34
Set-Cookie: filehosting=sd81k9t4pibbhf284ntrbl0htk; expires=Fri, 10-Nov-2023 05:03:17 GMT; Max-Age=8640000; path=/
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
X-Cache: Fron <<URL>>
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=S7E9dV3mcsOD1xXM%2Bz5MgfKisq0UDlXNUJu5ywDqxg1%2F9JYRm26x56bybAGKKTepdvRpiEWmlOg2oiuMcg7RJWddtQ8ZxXDuynbdMRCu7ClPkUlbvuIZptahmd8dEA%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
NEL: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 7f03c6054cd48dde-MIA
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"
}
    IsSuccessStatusCode: True
    ReasonPhrase: "OK"
    RequestMessage: {Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://<<URL>>/login.html', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent, Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/json
  Content-Length: 69
}}
    StatusCode: OK {200}
    TrailingHeaders: {}
    Version: {1.1}
```

So it appears that it is a successful connection.  But when I make subsequent requests, the remote server acts like it doesn't know me.

The remote requests are done in a background worker if that makes a difference.

Note:  << URL >> is not the actual URL I am requesting, I just put it there as a placeholder (along with myUserName and MyPassword).

I have searched high and low, but most examples are using the obsolete web functions and/or are in c# and not vb.net.

EDIT:  As requested, this is the subsequent call that is made by the background worker (there are four workers).  This code works (see [Is it possible to have an async process executed in a BackgroundWorker (vb.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76797181/is-it-possible-to-have-an-async-process-executed-in-a-backgroundworker-vb-net)) but it is being executed as if I was not signed in.

```
 Try
     webReq = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, sAddressBar)
     webResponse = Client.Send(webReq)
     inStream = New StreamReader(webResponse.Content.ReadAsStream)
     sSource = inStream.ReadToEnd.Trim

     inStream.Close()
     webReq.Dispose()
 Catch
     MsgBox("Unable to open URL link!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Ripper Error")

     e.Cancel = True

     Exit Sub
 End Try
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are using to make the subsequent requests which are failing.